# Binding won't work(windows phone)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone

I have a problem with binding. Deserialize was successful, after deserialization I made a collection for binding, here I is my problem(from output):

```
(first property)System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Artist' property not found on ''Nirvana'' 'System.String' (HashCode=-816891269). BindingExpression: Path='Artist' DataItem=''Nirvana'' (HashCode=-816891269); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
(second property)System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'SongName' property not found on ''Nirvana'' 'System.String' (HashCode=-816891269). BindingExpression: Path='SongName' DataItem=''Nirvana'' (HashCode=-816891269); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

this is my class:

```
internal class VkResponse 
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public List<Song> Musics { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{       
    public Song(string artist, string song, string uri)
    {
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.SongName = song;
        this.SongUri = uri;
    }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "artist")]
    public string Artist { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string SongName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string SongUri { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dutation")]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner_id")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lyrics_id")]
    public int LyricsId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre_id")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my deserialization:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> SongsColl { get; set; }
    // Конструктор
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        Loaded +=MainPage_Loaded;
    }
        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SongsColl = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                this.SpinningAnimation.Begin();
                JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
                JArray array = (JArray)jobject["response"];                   
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VkResponse>(json);
                for (int count = 0; count < response.Musics.Count; count++)
                {
                    //this.sListBox.ItemsSource = response.Musics[count].ToString();
                    SongsColl.Add(response.Musics[count].Artist.ToString());
                    SongsColl.Add(response.Musics[count].SongName.ToString());
                    SongsColl.Add(response.Musics[count].SongUri.ToString());
                    sListBox.ItemsSource = SongsColl;

                }                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                this.SpinningAnimation.Stop();
                this.CsEllipse.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;                    
            }

        }
    }
```

little update, sorry, XAML:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="sListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SongColl}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you please share XAML as well?

Comment: Sorry, so this is my xaml: 'code' <ListBox x:Name="sListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SongColl}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

Comment: Hi Nikita can you update your question and add XAML just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want display a list of song titles and show song details when element in listbox is clicked.

To do this, you must have a collection of Songs and special property which will contain a **selected** song.

```
public ObservableCollection<Song> Songs {get;set;}
public Song SelectedSong {get;set;}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Songs = response.Musics;
}
```

In XAML:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding SelectedSong.Title}/>
<TextBox Text={Binding SelectedSong.Artist}/>
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Songs} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedSong, Mode=TwoWay}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Title} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>     
</ListBox>
```

Pay attention to listbox `SelectedItem` binding - `Mode=TwoWay` is specified. This means the property `SelectedSong` will be updated from view when selected item changes.

Listbox item template is required because listbox doesn't know how to display a `Song` object. You also can override `ToString` method in `Song` class, but it's not recommended.

**EDIT**
Finally, your view model should notify the view when you assign a new value to `Songs` collection.

Comment: I am decided to delete my mvvm, just because that's not useful. If you want to see my xaml, I added in comments upper. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: It's not easy to understand mvvm pattern and its cons at first time. MVVM is useful event when you don't use UnitTests. It's layer of abstraction, programmatic UI. (I can help you in russian language if you need)

Comment: I have a problems with explain my thoughts, but I trying to improve my knowledge, so let's get back to my problem. Do you have another way to bind (ObservableCollection<>/List<>)collection? If you have, please, show me.

Comment: You can bind collection to listbox as you did before in code-behind. Just set `ItemsSource = songs`